# Json-Schema-Validator in OSGI Environment

Tags: osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle, karaf, json-schema-validator

I was trying to use Json-schema-Validator in osgi (Equinox) environment and it was not successful. The bundles were up and running. I'm getting ClassDefNotFOundException.

```
Exception in thread "[ACCESS_RUNTIME] ActivityInitialize-Thread-1"         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:607)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.<init>(JsonNodeReader.java:82)
at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.<clinit>(JsonLoader.java:45)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<init>(SchemaVersion.java:63)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<clinit>(SchemaVersion.java:44)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfigurationBuilder.<init>(LoadingConfigurationBuilder.java:117)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfiguration.byDefault(LoadingConfiguration.java:151)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.<init>(JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.java:67)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder(JsonSchemaFactory.java:121)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(JsonSchemaFactory.java:111)
```

Command find-class  shows it could find the class. But am getting the error in runtime. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to diagnose the problem with juat the stack trace. Please provide which bundles you installed and how the Manifest of your own bundle looks like.

Comment: (author here) What @ChristianSchneider says, and also open an issue on the project page please.